# No internet when switching from a wired connection to another

Tags: 22.04, internet, laptop, wired

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a Laptop with a wired access to internet at home, and when I bring my laptop to our local radio station without shutting it down and try to access to internet there via an ethernet cable, the network is not detected. Unfortunately I did not try elsewhere yet, so can't confirm if the problem is reproduced elsewhere.

I tried :

- stopping/restarting the wired network connection through Ubuntu's network manager
- stopping/restarting the network manager via systemctl
  None of that worked.

The only solution I found until now is rebooting...

When the network is not detected via the wired connection, if I enable the wifi the connection is correctly enabled and I have access to internet (unfortunately this is not a solution because for various reasons I want to use the wired connection). I know tha

Any hints on where to look for to solve the problem is appreciated.
Also if anyone knows how to reset the connection without rebooting the whole system would greatly help as a temporary workaround.

I can provide logs if needed.

Thanks !